# Gradle and Dependencies supported Java version

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle

How do I make sure that the dependencies I use in Gradle are compatible with a given Java version?

For example, I created an application that uses GraalVM. In Gradle I specify:

```
    implementation 'org.graalvm.js:js:22.2.0'
    implementation 'org.graalvm.js:js-scriptengine:22.2.0'
```

When executing the code I get:

```
Error loading driver /Users/yusuf-mac/.DbSchema/drivers/MongoDb/truffle-api-22.2.0.jar : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: META-INF/versions/17/module-info has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 59.0. 
Please consider upgrading Java. Your current Java version is AdoptOpenJDK 15.0.2.
```

How do I ensure in Gradle that the dependencies are compatible with OpenJDK 15? I cannot upgrade to a higher version of OpenJDK. Is any way to make sure that the dependency version 22.2.0 is compatible with OpenJDK 15?

Here the complete build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
plugins{
    id "java"
    id 'org.hidetake.ssh' version '2.7.1'
}
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'distribution'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(15)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.7.1'
    implementation 'org.graalvm.js:js:22.2.0'
    implementation 'org.graalvm.js:js-scriptengine:22.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    //implementation "org.graalvm.sdk:graal-sdk:22.0.0.2"
    //implementation "org.graalvm.truffle:truffle-api:22.0.0.2"
}

compileJava{
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
                '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
        ]
    }
}

jar {
    archiveName ="mongojdbc${version}.jar"
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.wisecoders.dbschema.mongodb.JdbcDriver'
        attributes 'Class-Path': configurations.runtimeClasspath.files.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')
        attributes 'Specification-Version': "$version"
        attributes 'Specification-Vendor': "Wise Coders"
        attributes 'Implementation-Vendor-Id': "dbschema.com"
        attributes 'Implementation-Vendor': "Wise Coders"
        attributes 'Implementation-Version': new Date().format( 'yyMMdd' )
    }
}


task zip(type: Zip, dependsOn:['clean','jar']) {
    archiveFileName.set 'MongoDbJdbcDriver.zip'
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath.allArtifacts.files
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath
    from "build/libs" include "*.jar"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to reproduce this behavior in a sample project I created - https://github.com/alexanderankin/so-73508929 - including [this library](https://github.com/alexanderankin/so-73508929/blob/b87df91793b0f1ad1db128aef4870976bebcce83/build.gradle#L13-L14) and [its use](https://github.com/alexanderankin/so-73508929/blob/main/src/main/java/pkg/Main.java).

I've also included the gradle [tool chain api](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#header) reference in the [build.gradle](https://github.com/alexanderankin/so-73508929/blob/be0a7a25c23f821dd209fdeca27bf68f51cc9547/build.gradle#L12-L21) script in my project to show how you would restrict the java version your project is validated against, although I'm pretty sure it would be easier to use a tool like [sdkman](https://sdkman.io) to quickly switch between java versions.

Your error message also indicates that the jar is coming from a mongo folder, so maybe its from something else in that project/environment.

Comment: it looks like the minimum version of that particular classfile on my machine is java 9 not 17 as it is on your machine

Comment: Thank you. If I look this page https://www.graalvm.org/java/quickstart/ they say there are two distributions of graalvm, for Java 11 and 17. Is any way to differentiate this in build.gradle? Does the toolchain throw an exception if the dependency is not compatible? The project produces a JDBC driver, which is loaded into other application using URLClassLoader. I will update the initial post with the complete build.gradle

Comment: so that would look like `java.toolchain.vendor.set JvmVendorSpec.GRAAL_VM` (or the groovy closure notation, `java { toolchain { // etc...`

Comment: @DbSchema - after looking into this a bit more, it seems like your issue stems from trying to use modules, my advice is simply don't use the evil things and you will be fine.